# Django Sphinx Error while importing

Tags: python, django, python-sphinx

I am getting below error while running `make html`

```
AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

My conf file contains the below conf for importing

```
import os
import sys    
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure()
```

docs is contained in my project folder. I have multiple apps.

Answer (score 0):

Try `setup`

```
import os
import sys    
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure()
import django
django.setup()
```

Comment: Getting below error with this - `Exception occurred:
  File "/home/tanmay/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 39, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting LOGGING_CONFIG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.`

Comment: This fails to import my module path - `RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
`

Comment: Do you have contenttypes application in your installed_apps? you must be using this but you did not include it in the installed apps. Try including this `'django.contrib.contenttypes'` in your installed apps in settings

Comment: It's there, I have a config folder with `installed_apps.py` file which is imported in the settings.

Comment: the error says the it can not find it. So it may be the issue that this app is not imported or loaded.

Comment: The import is there, issue is peculiar, I created a an example model without foreign key so that it doesn't use ContentType, It was also showing the error that model doesn't define an explicit app label. So I defined inner class Meta with app_label. It then worked. But still not working for my original model even with Meta class since it tries ContentType model, how can I solve the same? And why do I need to add Meta class. This is tedious.